# Time-reversal procedure for spin

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, time-reversal-symmetry

What's the physical reason/explanation for the fact when time is reversed then, in addition to momentum of fermion, spin is also reversed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the spin is an actual magnetic moment, then its behavior under time reversal is simply similar to that of classical magnetization, which changes sign. Think of magnetic fields and dipoles as generated by electric currents. Under time reversal the currents reverse direction and so do the corresponding magnetic fields or dipoles. At quantum level, spin reversal goes hand in hand with the reversal of orbital and total angular momentum (orbital and total magnetic moments), and with CPT symmetry.

This lecture gives a nice presentation: [Time reversal](http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/9697/timerev.pdf)

Comment: This answer is not complete I feel, in the case of half-integer spin you don't just reverse the sign of the spin, but you also get an additional phase factor $i$, which underlies the Kramers theorem and makes fermions different from bosons.

Comment: @KFGauss Unlike $\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times \vec{p}$, the spin $\vec{S}$ cannot be defined like this. Therefore, it is not possible to deduce the time-reversal property of $\vec{S}$ from the definition of ${\vec S}$.

Comment: Perhaps the best justification is what your reference hints for: if we define its action over S just like over L, then the action over J is the same as well...